# Empty TextEditingController value after Get.offAllNamed with fenix: true

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

**Problem:** I get empty data from `TextEditingController` after returning to page with `Get.offAllNamed` and using **fenix: true** for binding

Login page has two `TextFormFields` tied with `TextEditingControllers` in the LoginLogic controller.

**login_page.dart**

```
/////
                     TextFormField(
                        controller: controller.usernameValueController,
                        validator: notEmptyValidator,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Login',
                        ),
                      )
/////
```

**login_logic.dart**

```
class LoginLogic extends GetxController {
  var usernameValueController = TextEditingController();
  var passwordValueController = TextEditingController();
/////
  void login() async {

    var loginRequest = LoginRequest(usernameValueController.text, passwordValueController.text)
//retrieve and save auth token,  
/////
}
```

**login_binding.dart**

```
class LoginBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<LoginLogic>(
          () => LoginLogic(), fenix: true
    );
  }
}
```

In case of auth token expiration user is transferred back to login with `Get.offAllNamed` method to prevent backstack navigation. But after login controller recreation TextEditingController doesn't receive any value from textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller will be deleted if the screen that called the contoller disposed if you want permanent controller change lazyput to Get.put in the binding

Comment: Using Get.put with permanent:true helped but I'm not sure is this the best solution. I thought that in this scenario controllers should be recreated and have same behavior as it was on launch.